# Benefit of using GlobalIDs in ArcSDE geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, replication

This may be somewhere, but I can't find a clear answer on exactly the benefit of GlobalIDs are in a database.  What are the benefits of using these in an organization that has about 6 people editing the same data.

Comment: The benefit is primarily *outside* of the database (in replicated copies), so you'd need to edit the question to give some context with respect to replication in your organization.

Answer (score 8):

It is a way to maintain object identity since the standard geodatabase objectids are not preserved after an export/import cycle. It enables you to uniquely identify your features across the entire database.

That should help understand why features like replication rely on this.

Comment: And lends the disconnected editing a handle also.

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything linking to this data? If it is all inclusive and is independent of any other data, I'm not sure a  GlobalID would be helping any. Or if you have some other code like FIPSID for county that is unique and refers to that element uniquely, a GlobalID won't be needed*.

*Just don't rely on the ObjectID to always be constant like was previously mentioned.

Comment: ObjectID and GlobalID are different datatypes, and have different purposes.  ObjectIDs are 32-bit integer (positive, non-zero, and generally sequential) while GlobalIDs are implemented with either strings or native UUID type (when supported) and are effectively random across 128 bits.

Comment: Different purposes? What exactly do you mean by this? They both uniquely identify a certain record. 1 is just persistent (and globally unique) and the other can be modified.  If you are using a gdb that does not support GlobalID's, and needed an auto-generated key to link data, you would use the ObjectID to link the data, you just would have to make a copy of the ObjectID before moving the data to keep the relationship

Comment: The question was about GlobalIDs (aka GUIDs, aka UUIDs) and your answer was about ObjectIDs.  They are similar, but different. ObjectIDs are *required* for all feature classes, and are used by ArcGIS to track graphic by table row and table row by graphic. In fact, an ObjectID is a prerequisite for the addition of GlobalID column by ArcGIS. GlobalIDs are more expensive to generate and use, and will always badly fragment when indexed.  GlobalIDs are only used when external persistent linkage is necessary, as in disconnected editing and replication.

Comment: Must have had a disconnect between my brain and fingers. Edited my response, thought I was talking about Globals but somehow typed Objectid.

Comment: Ahh, yes, now this makes much more sense.